# When solving the Schrodinger Equation, where do we add the condition that $E$ is real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I'm reading through Griffiths, and I noticed two seemingly contradictory facts:

1. In Chapter 1, it is proved that for any square-integrable function solving the Schrodinger Equation, $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\Psi|^{2}dx = 0.\tag{1}$$
2. In Chapter 2, we solve the Schrodinger Equation using the separation of variables, and while never assuming that the separation constant $E$ must be real, we get the solutions
   $$\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}.\tag{2}$$
   Clearly, (as is shown in Problem 2.1 (a)), if $E$ is not real, the normalization condition proved in Chapter 1 does not hold.

So, we proved eq. (1) for any solution, and yet, when solving using separation of variables without assuming $E$ is real, we got solutions (2), which do not conform to the first condition if $E$ is not real.

During the solution process, where do we mathematically argue that $E$ must be real?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator): “The spectrum of a self-adjoint operator is real.”

Comment: I'm sure that at some point, somewhere, Griffiths must have written that the Hamiltonian is an "observable" that satisfies: $\hat H = \hat H^\dagger$... All observables have real eigenvalues... otherwise how would we observe them?

Comment: The formalism of linear operators is introduced in chapter 3. If you are still in chapter 2, you can instead show the realness of E in other ways, for example, using the explicit form of the Hamiltonian in positions space and integrating by parts twice.

Comment: There is a practice problem in chapter 2 that might have prompted your concern. The practice problem asks you to show that if the wave-function is to remain normalized for all time then E must be real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)e^{-iEt/\hbar}$, which do not conform to the first condition if E is not real.

> During the solution process, where do we mathematically argue that E must be real?

When you performed the separation of variables you wrote:
$$
i\frac{d f}{d t} = Ef
$$
and
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} + V\psi = E\psi\;,
$$
where $V$ is a real potential function, and where the full wave-function was written in seperable form like: $\Psi(x,t)=f(t)\psi(x)$.

Since your solution $\psi(x)$ is normalized we can write:
$$
\int \left[\psi^*(x)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}\right) + V\psi^*(x)\psi(x)\right]dx = E\;,
$$

Thus:
$$
E^* = \int \left[\psi(x)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 \psi^*}{dx^2}\right) + V\psi(x)\psi(x)^*\right]dx
$$

Then integrate by parts twice and use the vanishing of the boundary terms  to see that:
$$
E^* = \int \left[\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2}\right)\psi^*(x) + V\psi(x)\psi(x)^*\right]dx = E
$$

The equation
$$
E^*=E
$$
shows that $E$ is real.

Comment: I see, so the fact that we are restricting ourselves to square-integrable solutions (meaning boundary terms are zero) implies that for those solutions, E is real?

Comment: This would make sense because the proof that the time derivative of the normalization constant is zero in Chapter 1 uses the fact that the wave function is square-integrable. But based on your answer, being square-integrable implies E is real, so the proof only holds for real values of E. Okay, this feels much better! Thank you for your explanation, it's really helped me square this logic in my brain!

Comment: @MatthewSmith Yes, the fact that the solutions are square-integrable is important. You will sometime see people use the notation $L^2$  or $L^2(X)$ to describe the set of square-integrable functions on the space $X$. Square integrability is important because otherwise we couldn't interpret $|\psi(x)|^2$ as a probability density (we couldn't normalize it). One caveat: you will also find that sometime it is convenient to make use of basis functions that are *not* square integrable (like plane waves), but the physical wave function will be square integrable.

Comment: Glad this helps.